# GetX passing data to other screen using only controller

Tags: flutter, api, dart

Ex: I have one controller on product screen and then I need to click on there product it will show product detail, it's correct scenario alter I have option for click view company profile and then on this company profile have some related product on the company, and then I need click view product related for view product detail, but it still show old data I was click first on product, it should be show lated data. not first data.
Anyone face an issue.
-> first

```
Get.toNamed(Routes.productDetail, arguments: {"supplierId": companyId, "product": product});
```

-> tow click from company profile view product detail

```
Get.toNamed(Routes.productDetail, arguments: {"supplierId": companyId, "product": product});
```

I think controller not init again.

Comment: Does the page for viewing product is also having same controller? Also does using parameters is also same not argruments?

Comment: Yes controller as the same and data I pass by argument.

Comment: how is your controller working? Where have you injected it?

Comment: If does i think the on init wont work on that since you didnt dispose the controller which also the on init is only once called so better create a value on that. Create a function which value changes like companyId , productId

Comment: Does the product is a model or a String?

Comment: Product is a model

Comment: @KrishBhanushali If we dispose controller so when click back data still stay the same?

Comment: Not necessarily if you have still needed on the controller

Comment: try below if this okay with you

Answer (score 1):

try this since both page have same controller i think the other page wont
try to call again the on init

```
    /// this is the value/s lets assume it.
    final supplierId = "".obs;
    final Rx<Product> product = Product().obs;
    
    
    //// Funtion to go page
    gotoProductDetail({String? companyId, Product? product1}){
  
    supplierId(companyId!);
    product(product1!);
////// use update if you are using GetBuilder
     update();
    Get.toNamed(Routes.productDetail);
    
    }
```

now access this data to the product detail

```
class ProductDetails extends StatelessWidget{
........
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return GetBuilder<YourController>(builder :(controller){
  
   return Scafold(
    body: Column(
      children: [
       Text(controller.product.value.name),
    ]
    )

  );
  });


  }
}
```